# My function dont work, Ajax call,JQuery, calling outside ? I dont know

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, attributes

if you want to understand my problem, please read every step of that shitty code that make me angry :

The context of all of this is an API, so I have to do an ajax call to an external JSon file. The call works : I get the response, and I can manage data like I wanna.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $.ajax({ 
         url: 'http://MY JSON URL/',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=windows-1252",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(content) {
                  var api = content.contents.response // Dont care about this, it work.
                  var AnyDataFromJsonIWantToGet = api.data // Dont care about this, it work.

    $('#myAPI').html("Some HTML content, syntax checked" +
                    $('#mainbuy').html() 
                    + "Some HTML content, syntax checked");    
   },
   /* Error */
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
              alert("No Json" + xhr.status);
      },
   
        
  });
```

As you can see, I call `$('#mainbuy').html()` in `$('#myAPI').html()`. My problem is in `$('#mainbuy').html()` but occur only when called in `$('#myAPI').html()`. Here is the main page HTML code for `$('#mainbuy').html()`, I keep all my `<div class>` and others `<div>` cause maybe you will find the source of my problem in it, but you will see later why I think its absolutely not about my CSS tricks.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="mainbuy" style="display:none;">
                   <div class="coachbtn"><div class="dropup"><div id="buybtn"> 
                      <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" id="pickhour" name="pickhour">
          <option value="1">1H</option>
          <option value="2" selected>2H</option>
          <option value="3">3H</option>
        <option value="4">4H</option>
          </select> 
                    </div></div></div>
                    <div class="coachbtn2"><div id="buybtn2">
                       <a id="egglink" class="button button-large" style="width: 260px">Reserver</a>
                    </div></div>
                     
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#pickhour').change(function(){
              pickhour1 = $(this).val();
              $("#egglink").attr("href", "http://my-link/" + pickhour1 + "/end/of/my/link/");
      });
       }); 
                </script>
                    </div>
```

So, in this :

-A dropdown select-box : ID "pickhour"

-A button (`<a></a> with style`) : ID "egglink"

- My script used to get the `.val()` of selected value in my select-box, and put it in a link which is `.attr()` href to my button.

The problematic :

If I show the select box + the button + the script in my main page without calling it elsewhere : It works fine !

If I want to show `<div id="mainbuy" style="display:none;">` with `$('#mainbuy').html()` in `$('#myAPI').html()` : The result is showing every elements like it should but the script dont work, no HREF on my button.

I dont know if it is important but I use Fancybox to open `$('#myAPI').html()` :

```html
<div id="openAPI" style="display:none;width:auto;height:auto;">
    <div id ='myAPI'>
</div></div>

<a class="hover-wrap fancybox-media" data-fancybox-group="video" title=" " href="#openAPI">
```

Im not really smart with JavaScript and actually Im lost in this, it seem to be easy and working, but its not.. :(

Thanks you for readind, I hope someone here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your DOM is not updated (cause your AJAX request), try this :

```
$('#buybtn2').on('change' , '#pickhour' , function(){
    pickhour1 = $(this).val();
    $("#egglink").attr("href", "http://my-link/" + pickhour1 + "/end/of/my/link/");
});
```

I don't know if that work..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in advance for my bad english.

it's not "#buybtn2" but "#buybtn" sorry for that.

Actually, you try to change href attribute, but this button doesn't have any href attribute. Maybe it's that your problem.

try to add a href at your button :

```
<div class="coachbtn2">
     <div id="buybtn2">
         <a id="egglink" class="button button-large" href="" style="width: 260px">Reserver</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same with a `href=""` :s

Comment: you try to change buybtn2 by buybtn ? in script js

Comment: `$('#buybtn').on('change' , '#pickhour' , function(){`

Comment: Your console display something ?  your button doesnt still have any href ?

Comment: Nothing particular in console, yeah so he got an empty href which return home page :
`<a id="egglink" class="button button-large" href="" style="width: 260px">Reserver un cours</a>`

Comment: donne moi ton skype  :)

Answer (score 0):

For the newest versions of jquery attr refers to the originally html.  So changing it won't update the DOM.  Try using prop instead.

```
$('#buybtn2').on('change' , '#pickhour' , function(){
    pickhour1 = $(this).val();
    $("#egglink").prop("href", "http://my-link/" + pickhour1 + "/end/of/my/link/");
});
```